# Is the webkit rendering engine same for safari in ios & mac os\ PC? Like wise is the blink rendering engine same for chrome in android and PC?

Tags: ios, selenium, webkit, automation, blink

To be more secific, here is my dilemma.

I am planning to start UI test automation of an m.com site.

Option 1 that have been put forward is to use commercial tools (quite costly) that runs these test cases on the device. In addition to tool cost i also need to procure devices

Option 2 is to use open source tools like webdriver, change the user agent for browsers like firefox, chrome and safari and run the test cases on a PC. (This is quite cost effective).

I prefer option 2 but here are my doubts

1) Is the webkit rendering engine same for ios and mac?
2) Is the blink rendering engine same for PC Chrome and android Chrome?
3) Will changing the user agent, but using the same browser and running the test cases (eg: change user agent of safari in PC to that of ios, but render in safari) give me the same results as that of testing on the device?

Comment: You will see some corner cases whereby issues present on the Mac but on not a PC and vice versa but no, user agent changing is not enough. In a very similar way the "compatibility mode" within IE aren't true representations of that version.

Answer (score 0):

1. Safari- browser in iOS and Mac uses Webkit as its layout/rendering engine
2. PC Chrome, Android Chrome uses Blink from April 2013 onwards

Having said that, iOS, Android browsers are compliant to standard HTML,JS, CSS syntax and standards, apart from that each browser may have their specific extensions or bleeding edge features, which may not be yet standardized.

Your testing is based on standard features, you need not worry much about the browser difference now.

Also, If you want to save headache of managing multiple browser, platform, you can try saucelabs.com (cloud based service selenium,test automation service)